# How can i execute my webbrowser in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, webbrowser-control, opera

I need to execute my webbrowser (opera) from python code, how can i get it?

Python version 3.6, OS MS Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **webbrowser** module in python.

```
import webbrowser as wb
wb.get('chrome %s').open_new_tab('http://www.google.com')
```

You can open your **default** web browser in python this way by writing this command in **cmd**:

```
python -mwebbrowser -n URL
```

**-n** : new window

Look at the [**`webbrowser`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) documentation to see other options as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium to launch web browser through python.